# Regex for single quote within single quotes

Tags: regex

OK, so this is what I'm trying to do :

- I've got a complete SQL script
- Some of the `'s` inside the values have not been properly escaped
- e.g. if we have `'children's shoes'`, I want to replace it with `'children\'s shoes'`

So, any suggestions? (I've tried various workarounds but I don't seem to be able to get it right...)

---

**UPDATE:**

- `'.+?'` sure matches the values - but how do I match the `'s`s within the values?
- Here's a RegExr example of what I'm trying to match : http://regexr.com?368bo

---

**UPDATE II :**

OK, I think I'll go with `[a-z]'s`. It seems like it's capturing what I need. And replace with `$1\'s`.

Comment: Since you tagged your question with regex, what was your last regex attempt?

Comment: @Jerry I've tried something like : `'.+?('s).+?'` but it seems to be too... greedy

Comment: @Downvoters What's the issue with the question? I've happily replied LOTS and LOTS of times on Regex-related questions, and one time I need some assistance I get downvoted? What is not clear about my requirements? :S

Comment: Don't do this. Ever. If the SQL statement is already invalid, go one step back and escape the parameters when you create the statement. It's not possible to do what you ask for.

Comment: How to know whether quoted string is not ending with 2nd quote i.e. `'children'`

Comment: @Prinzhorn The SQL statement has been created by a custom PHP script which took some *hours* to complete. And yep, my bad, I forgot to escape the damn quotes. However, the statement can be fixed - I've done it manually - I just want to save some time... :-)

Comment: @anubhava it's a list of SQL `INSERT` statements, with the values like `VALUES ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five')` - what I need is to match `'s`s *within* 2 single-quotes.

Comment: So you are always matching `'s`?

Comment: @anubhava Have a look at my update in the original post. ;-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon I'm not sure what SQL can accept as regex, but is [this](http://regexr.com?368br) what you are looking for?

Comment: @Jerry It doesn't have to do with SQL. It's just a text file which just *happens* to have SQL in it. The point is to make it valid so that I can execute it as a MySQL query. :-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Oh, okay! Dod you have a look at the link I provided in my previous comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match this regex:

```
('[^']*)'s([^']*')
```

And replace with:

```
$1\'s$2
```

#### Live Demo: http://regexr.com?368bu

Comment: Perfect. You nailed it! Thanks a lot! :-)