# How to escape single quotes inside single-quoted SQL strings in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to fix a bug in [this crude script](https://github.com/memoz/acd-scripts/blob/master/packer.sh) that chokes on directory names containing single quotes. There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672629/regex-for-single-quote-within-single-quotes), but it only escapes one single quote.

The SQL queries look like these:

```
SELECT arc_no, password, status FROM summary WHERE arc_no = (SELECT name FROM dir_tree WHERE node_id = (SELECT parent_id FROM dir_tree WHERE name = '${bash_args[0]}'))::BIGINT
SELECT arc_no, password, status FROM summary WHERE descr = '${bash_args[0]}'
INSERT INTO summary (arc_no, act_size, dirs, files, status, password, descr) VALUES ('$arc_no', '${s_d_f[0]}', '${s_d_f[1]}', '${s_d_f[2]}', 'packing', '$a_pwd', '${bash_args[0]}')
```

So a directory named "A's files concerning B's work" would generate:

```
SELECT arc_no, password, status FROM summary WHERE descr = 'A's files concerning B's work'
```

That would raise a syntax error.

To get this:

```
SELECT arc_no, password, status FROM summary WHERE descr = 'A''s files concerning B''s work'
```

Can I use sed and possibly covering directory names beginning or ending with single quotes? Or am I better off with more sophisticated languages such as python?

Comment: Essentially all you need to do is double the single quotes in a variable, and then insert *that* with single-quotes around it.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Yup, that's what I was trying to do. I'm feeling stupid after reading gniourf_gniourf's answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the expansion

```
${bash_args[0]}
```

with

```
${bash_args[0]//\'/\'\'}
```

See [*Shell Parameter Expansion* in the reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Similarly with your other variables: replace

```
$arc_no
```

by

```
${arc_no//\'/\'\'}
```